# Table lock during transaction contains max()

Tags: mysql

If I understand correctly this code

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT field FROM table WHERE ... FOR UPDATE ; // single row
    UPDATE table SET field = ... ;
COMMIT;
```

will lock the `SELECT` row until `COMMIT`.

But if I use `MAX()`

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT MAX(field) FROM table WHERE ... FOR UPDATE ; // whole table
    UPDATE table SET field = ... ;
COMMIT;
```

will this code lock the whole table until `COMMIT`?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I have my question wrong.
Obviously above code will lock rows affected by `WHERE`. But it wouldn't lock the table. Meaning

```
INSERT INTO table() VALUES();
```

could still took place regardless of `COMMIT`.
That would mean the return value of

```
SELECT MAX(field) FROM table WHERE ... FOR UPDATE ;
```

is now no longer valid.

How to lock the table during transaction so neither `INSERT` nor `UPDATE` could took place before `COMMIT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you're selecting. `FOR UPDATE` locks all the rows that have to be examined to evaluate the `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, another transaction could change the columns that are mentioned there, so the later `UPDATE` would assign to different rows.

And since inserting a new row can change the value of `MAX(field)`, it actually locks the entire table. When I try your example, and try to insert a new from another transaction, the second transaction blocks until I commit the first transaction.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this wrong. I've updated my question. Would you mind to update your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I just did a test. The transaction trying to do the insert blocks until the first transaction is committed.